What is the difference between the version of PhpSpreadsheet in the composer.lock file and the release on GitHub?
In the composer.lock file I see that the version is 1.29, but on GitHub it says release 3.6.0. What is the difference between the two? The documentation seems to refer to the version listed on GitHub.
